# How python3 converts bytes to floats?

Tags: python

I’d like to understand how python converts bytes to floats, in detail.
Let’s create a binary file containing just one float 23.0:

```
~> echo 23 > 23.a  
~> a2b < 23.a n1=1 > 23.b
```

Let’s now write a python3 code 23.py:

```
~> cat 23.py  
import struct
f='23.b'                                            
fd=open(f,'rb')                                      # Open the file
value_bytes=fd.read()                                # Read file, 4 bytes in total
                                                     # Output:
print("Bytes =",value_bytes)                         # Bytes = b'\x00\x00\xb8A'
print("Float =",struct.unpack("<f",value_bytes))     # Float = (23.0,)
```

Execute the code:

```
~> python3.5 23.py  
Bytes = b'\x00\x00\xb8A'  
Float = (23.0,)
```

So, I am wondering how python converts the bytes '\x00\x00\xb8A' into float 23.0? This has something to do with the DEC-BIN-HEX-ASCII representation, but I have already broken my brain trying to understand this.

```
DEC = 23  
BIN = 0000 0000 0001 0111  
HEX =    0    0    1    7
```

How do we get '\x00\x00\xb8A' from it? Or vice-versa, how '\x00\x00\xb8A' transforms into 23.0?
Could anyone explain me step by step? Thanks.

Comment: What does the `a2b` command do? None of my Debian, CentOS, or OS X systems have that command.

Comment: @Martijn You are right, I've overlooked that. That's part of "Seismic Unix". Reads ascii floats line by line and converts them to binary. Little endian, I believe, in this case.

Comment: Right, so that's [this tool](http://www.cwp.mines.edu/sututor/node33.html) then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is clearly [documented in the format table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters):

> For the `'f'` and `'d'` conversion codes, the packed representation uses the IEEE 754 binary32 (for `'f'`) or binary64 (for `'d'`) format, regardless of the floating-point format used by the platform.

So to understand that format, reference the [IEEE floating point standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point); you used the `f` code, so look for the [binary32, or *single precision* format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

This format consists of 32 bits, divided over:

- Sign bit: 1 bit
- Exponent width: 8 bits
- Significand precision: 24 bits (23 explicitly stored)

Looking at your binary data as bits, (which you treat as little endian, so I'm reversing these to match the Wikipedia big-endian ordering):

```
>>> ('{:08b}' * 4).format(*b'\x00\x00\xb8A'[::-1])
'01000001101110000000000000000000'
```

we see that the sign is 0, the exponent width is 131 (in 2's complement, so minus 127 makes 4), and the significand precision or mantissa is 1.4375 (1 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16, each binary fraction is an enabled bit).

```
>>> ('{:08b}' * 4).format(*b'\x00\x00\xb8A'[::-1])[:1]  # sign
'0'
>>> ('{:08b}' * 4).format(*b'\x00\x00\xb8A'[::-1])[1:9]  # exponent, signed
'10000011'
>>> int(('{:08b}' * 4).format(*b'\x00\x00\xb8A'[::-1])[1:9], 2) - 127  # exponent, signed
4
>>> ('{:08b}' * 4).format(*b'\x00\x00\xb8A'[::-1])[9:]  # mantissa
'01110000000000000000000'
>>> # That's the 1/4 bit plus the 1/8th bit plus the 1/16th bits all enabled.
...
>>> 1 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16
1.4375
```

Together these form the actual floating point value:

```
>>> 1 * 2 ** 4 * 1.4375 (sign, positive, times 2 to the power exponent, times fractions)
23.0
```

---

To go the other way, express the whole integer number and the value after the decimal point in binary; you may have to *approximate* the non-integer portion as binary fractions can't express all possible real numbers. 23.0 has no non-integer component, so that is easy here, we only have to convert the integer component to binary:

```
>>> format(23, 'b')
'10111'
```

So the binary representation for the real number is `10111.0`. You then shift the decimal point up or down to get `1` and a fraction; here you need to shift the decimal point up 4 spots to `1.0111`. This gives you the exponent (4), and the significant (0111 plus another 19 zeros for the unused fractions). The value is positive, so you encode the sign as `0`, the exponent as a signed value (add 127 == 131, encode 131 to binary == `10000011`), and add the significant:

```
0 10000011 01110000000000000000000
```

Chopping that into 4 groups of 8 bits (4 bytes) gives you `0x41 0xB8 0x00 0x00`. Python's `repr()` output for a byte gives you printable ASCII characters for bytes where possible, and `0x41` is the letter `A` in the ASCII table:

```
>>> bytes([0b01000001, 0b10111000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000])
b'A\xb8\x00\x00'
```

Reverse those bytes for a little-endian representation:

```
>>> bytes([0b01000001, 0b10111000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000])[::-1]
b'\x00\x00\xb8A'
```

---

You can visualise how the IEEE binary32 format works with [this online converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

Comment: OK, thanks. It is clear now how to convert the 32binary into IEEE float. But I am still missing, how we get '01000001101110000000000000000000' from b'\x00\x00\xb8A', and b'\x00\x00\xb8A' from 23.

Comment: @Michael: `b'\x00\x00\xb8A` represents 4 bytes, values 0, 0, 184 and 65 in decimal, but printed as ASCII where possible (ASCII 65 is `'A'`). Reversing those bytes first (little endian to big endian) and converting those to binary representations give you 01000001 10111000 00000000 00000000.

Comment: @Michael: as for going from 23.0 to the binary representation, see the [*decimal representation to binary32 format* section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Converting_from_decimal_representation_to_binary32_format). `23.0` is `10111.0` in binary (with binary fractions), but that value is 'normalised' by shifting 4 steps to the right to `'1.0111'`. That way you only need to encode `4` as the exponent and `0111` as the mantissa.

Comment: Ah, that's it. The ASCII representation combined with byte reversal was not quite obvious, but I finally got it, thanks to you!